# Preload an angular module based on a users role

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm playing around with a custom preloading strategy for my angular app. So far I can preload a module based on a true/false value that I pass in through my routes.

**router.module.ts**

```
...
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AppWrapperComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'path1',
        loadChildren: './routes/path-one/path-one.module#PathOneModule',
        data: { preload: false }
      },
      {
        path: 'path2',
        loadChildren: './routes/path-two/path-two.module#PathTwoModule',
        data: { preload: true }
      }
];
...
```

**custom-preload-strategy.ts**

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { PreloadingStrategy, Route } from '@angular/router';

export class PreloadSelectedModulesList implements PreloadingStrategy {

    preload(route: Route, preload: Function): Observable<any> {
        if (route.data && route.data.preload) {
            return preload();
        } else {
            return Observable.of(null);
        }
    }
}
```

I would eventually like to optimize this further by preloading a module based on a user's role. The problem is that the preloading strategy runs when a user hits the login page and since the user isn't logged in yet I have no way of preloading based on that user's role. Is there any way to defer all preloading until a user logs in and then check a service for the roles and preload based off of that information? Perhaps there is a way using Rxjs?